# Reducing the space around $\upharpoonright$

Tags: spacing

I am writing a small project based on Jech's book "Set theory". When he writes `$p \upharpoonright (s^{\frown} a)$`, the space around the `$\upharpoonright$` is quite small, whereas when I write it, the space is quite big. For comparison, see the following pictures

Jech's:

[image: Jech:]

Mine:

[image]

What can I do to make the space smaller?

Comment: Can you also post an image from the book?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It suffices to wrap it into braces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\noindent
$p\upharpoonright(s)$ 

\noindent
$p{\upharpoonright}(s)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`\upharpoonright` behaves as, say, + sign. You can say that it has got empty arguments:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

Instead of
\[
A\upharpoonright B
\]
you want
\[
A{\upharpoonright} B
\]

\end{document}
```

I hope that the resulting picture is unneeded, but if you want...